# Do we say that life expectancy is "higher" or "longer"?

Tags: word-choice

E.g. Life expectancy in Japan is higher/longer than in Russia.

Or perhaps both are correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think "higher" makes more sense, since it is describing the word "expectancy." Expectations are higher or lower, not shorter or longer.